# d3 tsvParser resulting in 1 column with the entire string instead of parsing it into objects

Tags: javascript, pandas, csv, d3.js

I am trying to parse a .tsv file into an array of objects so I can pass the array into react-stockcharts to display a chart.

Here is a working example from react-stockcharts: https://codesandbox.io/s/2ox5z7w310

I used pandas in Python to send a .tsv file to my client, like so:

```
return data.to_csv(sep='\t'), 201, {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
```

I receive the data fine, and then convert it to a string with JS's .text():

```
.then(res => {
  res = res.text()
  return res
})
```

I can print the string and it looks as expected. Here is a small sample of the part of the string that represents the first few rows:

```
"Epoch\tOpen\tHigh\tLow\tClose\tVolume\n2017-08-17 04:00:00+00:00\t4261.48\t4261.48\t4261.48\t4261.48\t1.775183\n2017-08-17 04:01:00+00:00\t4261.48\t4261.48\t4261.48\t4261.48\t0.0\n"
```

I create a parser for the time to be in the proper format for react-stockcharts to take in:

```
const parseDate = timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z")
```

Then when I parse it, like so:

```
str = tsvParse(str, function(d) {
  return {
    date: parseDate(d.Epoch), 
    open: d.Open, 
    high: d.High,
    low: d.Low,
    close: d.Close, 
    volume: d.Volume 
  }
})
return str;
```

It returns this, passing the entire string as 1 column into the array of columns, instead of parsing it into objects:

```
[columns: Array(1)]
columns: ["Epoch\tOpen\tHigh\tLow\tClose\tVolume\n2017-08-17 …0:00\t6577.62\t6577.62\t6577.62\t6577.62\t0.002\n"]
0: "Epoch\tOpen\tHigh\tLow\tClose\tVolume\n2017-08-17 "
length: 1
```

I tried using d3's tsvParseRows and it returns this:

```
[{…}]
0: {date: null, open: undefined, high: undefined, low: undefined, close: undefined, …}
length: 1
```

I dunno what that means but thought I would post in case it was helpful somehow.

Why is the entire string being sent into the column array instead of parsing correctly into an array of objects?

Code:

Check here for a working example that demonstrates what my app should do when parsing a .tsv file: https://codesandbox.io/s/74rn0km99q

This is my Flask app.py serving up my .tsv file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
from flask_restful import reqparse
import pymarketstore as pymkts
import talib
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__);
api = Api(app)

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('exchange_symbol', type=str, default='binance-BTCUSDT', help='Provide exchange_symbol')
parser.add_argument('interval', type=str, default='1Min', help='Provide interval')



class RSI(Resource):
  def get(self):
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # exchange_symbol = 'binance-BTCUSDT'
    # args['interval'] = '1Min'
    datatype = 'OHLCV'

    param = pymkts.Params(args['exchange_symbol'], args['interval'], datatype)

    cli = pymkts.Client('_private_data_source_web_address_goes_here')

    reply = cli.query(param)
    data = reply.first().df()
    return data.to_csv(sep='\t'), 201, {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}

api.add_resource(RSI, '/')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

SOLUTION:

Needed to .json() before passing to tsvParse, like so:

BROKEN:

```
.then(res => {
  res = res.text()
  return res
})
```

FIXED:

```
.then(res => {
  res = res.json()
  return res
})
```

Comment: Can you post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the problem (i.e. post the whole code chunk involved in fetching and parsing the TSV to ensure that there is not anything else affecting the text parsing).

Comment: @ialarmedalien yes I have edited my post to include the code

Comment: You can parse TSV directly using [d3-fetch's tsv](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/blob/master/README.md#tsv) -- just do `d3.tsv('data.tsv', function(d){ ...` where you have used `d3.tsvParse` -- no need to do any extra string conversion.

Comment: @ialarmedalien I got the exact same answer as I did before with tsvParse after changing to tsv:

export function getData() {
    const promiseCompare = tsv("http://xxx.x.x.x:xxxx/?exchange_symbol=binance-BTCUSDT&interval=1Min")
    .then(function (data) {
        data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.open = +d.open;
        d.high = +d.high;
        d.low = +d.low;
        d.close = +d.close;
        d.volume = +d.volume;
      })
        return data
    })

    return promiseCompare;
}

Comment: what do you get if you `console.log(data)` as the first thing you do in `.then(function(data){...}`?

Comment: @ialarmedalien The same thing as before. A single column with one array with a single string of the entire tsv string

[columns: Array(1)]
columns: ["Epoch\tOpen\tHigh\tLow\tClose\tVolume\n2017-08-17 …0\t6326.75\t6329.93\t6325.61\t6325.61\t1.845274\n"]
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: have you tried saving the output of your python app to a file and reading that in? It sounds like there's something weird going on with line endings or that your python app is not producing what it should be producing.

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to .json() the Response first. That returned the .tsv and from there I was able to tsvParse it. Thanks for taking the time to help sort it out @ialarmedalien